# Dependency-injection throws NullPointerException in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

here is my problem: I'm working with SpringMVC and I get a NullPointerException on calling an @Autowired dependency.

Here is the @Service:

```
package x.y.z.service

@Repository("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
   /* ... */
}
```

The service is autowired everywhere in the application without problems, except here:

```
package x.y.z.utils

@Component
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public TestClass() {
    super();
    }

    public void tester() {
    myService.find(1);
    }
}
```

where the method `tester()` throws the NP Exception on `myService`. When tracing the logs I see that the bean *is* managed by Spring.

The application context file is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />   

    <interceptors>
        <!-- ... -->
    </interceptors>

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

    <beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

</beans:beans>
```

And the referenced controllers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to 
        configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z" />
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

After a two days search I can't find anything helping. Am I missing something?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z"/>
```

In addition, please add:

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
```

**Update:**

I'm sorry but your xml is incorrect in terms of schema and it is missing what I told you to add:

This is how your file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

Comment: Both are already there. In fact, the bean is managed by Spring.

Comment: Please post your applicationContext xml file.

Comment: See my response and don't forget to add Spring dependencies to your classPath.

Comment: Hi, in my file I use an import on a controllers.xml file, where there are the two configurations and all the schema. I updated the question, thx!

Comment: Hi, You don't have component scan enabled. this is why your autowiring is not working. as soon as you will add it according to my example. it will be ok.